# Mazda 323 F loses power then comes back randomly?

Tags: mazda, supplemental-restraint-system, power-loss

My Mazda 323 F is driving me mad and I might have to scrap it. I have taken the car to the mechanics and they have changed spark plugs, leads and coil packs. All on separate occasions and all costing a few quid. When coil packs were changed the car didn't lose power for long period. But now it's doing it again.

When they plug it into a computer the readout either says it's fine or it can't read it.

For a while (2 years) the lights for the airbags have been on and that doesn't show up on computer reading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!It seems you've asked several questions or possibly are considering disperate questions here ... could you edit your question and clarify exactly where you're going with it? The airbags will require a different reader from the standard OBDII reader (requires the SRS reading capability). This may be why you're not seeing anything about the airbags. If the other part is about the coils or it running properly, you've not stated your exact question. Please edit and put further information for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Intermittent problems are a nightmare to diagnose-hwever, as there are 4 plugs, 4 coils, i would doubt all 4 fail at the same time-however, there is one fuel pump and i would suggest this may be the area to look at as if this failed, it would lose power-could be a loose connection etc...

Answer (score 0):

Of course this could have a few causes, but one thing that is easy to check and change is the fuel filter.  Well, its easy to locate and change on some cars.  Its an absolute pain on some other cars, as it can be in the fuel tank or somewhere harder to reach.

If you can take it out, have a very good look at it, flush it with fuel or spray cleaner and see what comes out.  If it looks even slightly dirty - replace it (or at least clean the filter, but they are hard to actually clean - get a new one).  I would replace it in any case, as they are cheap and can be blocked but look clean.

A dirty fuel filter can cause these exact symptoms.  (And if the fuel filter is dirty, I'm sure your fuel pump would be damaged - as mentioned in another Answer here that your pump could be faulty)